# CustomFont doesn't work on Marshmallow using fontFamily

Tags: android, fonts, textview, custom-font, typeface

I am targeting SDK version 27
I use this in my layout:

```
 <TextView
            android:id="@+id/logo_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:fontFamily="@font/source_sans_pro_regular"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/logo"
            android:text="@string/passenger_name"
            android:textColor="@color/gray32"
            android:textSize="38dp" />
```

I have different fonts that I use on different textview.
I have the font in my resourcesFont

This works perfectly on Android 8. But on a Nexus 6 with 6.0.1. it doesn't change my fonts.
Is there a way to fix this?

### EDIT

I have made a font resource called: sans_pro

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<font-family xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<font
    android:font="@font/source_sans_pro_regular"
    android:fontStyle="normal"
    android:fontWeight="400"

    app:font="@font/source_sans_pro_regular"
    app:fontStyle="normal"
    app:fontWeight="400" />
</font-family>
```

I set it on my textView.

```
  <TextView
            android:id="@+id/logo_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:fontFamily="@font/sans_pro"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/logo"
            android:text="@string/passenger_name"
            android:textColor="@color/gray32"
            android:textSize="38dp" />
```

But it still doesn't work.
If I do programmatically it works. Why doesn't it work from xml, am I missing something?
`((TextView) base.findViewById(R.id.logo_text)).setTypeface(ResourcesCompat.getFont(getActivity(), R.font.sans_pro_extralight));`

Am using this support library: 
`implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'`

Answer (score 0):

You should use the Support Library provides support to the Fonts in XML feature on devices running Android 4.1 (API level 16) and higher.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml

Comment: For this I wasn't sure. I 100% need to use programmatically
`Typeface typeface = ResourcesCompat.getFont(context, R.font.myfont);`
Is there no other way to just fix it using xml layouts code or the styles?

Comment: You need to create font resource and put the code there, I understand now. But I have another question, if I have different weight how can I select from my font family which to use:

    `<font app:fontStyle="normal" app:fontWeight="400" app:font="@font/source_sans_pro_regular"/>`
    `<font app:fontStyle="normal" app:fontWeight="500" app:font="@font/source_sans_pro_semibold"/>`

Answer (score 0):

You should use AndroidX library and replace `TextView` with `androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView`.